# CSV being read with no rows

Tags: python, pandas, csv, import

I'm trying to read a csv from a web page into pandas but get something saying empty dataframe and an object with 0 rows and 155 columns.  I feel like I'm missing a step.  Struggling to use data from web as opposed to my machine in general.

```
url ="https://data.world/exercises/data-wrangling-exercise-1/workspace/file?filename=Crime_2015.csv"
crimex= pd.read_csv(url)
print(crimex)
```

output as follows:

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [ data.world     Loading...?Feedback{"dataset":{"hasError":false, loadedDatasets:{}, usersDatasets:{}, loadedCurrentUsersDatasets:false, usersDatasetsTotalCount:0}, user:{"hasError":false, loadedUsers:{}, userFollows:{}, userLikes:{}, userInvites:null, userRecentComments:{}, groupAuthorizations:{}}, invite:{}, treatments:["showVersions", showWorkspaceTabs, showEntityLinkOptions, paramQueries], currentUser:{"authorizedAccounts":null, requests:[], unDismissedTourCount:2, needsAnalyticsAlias:false, notifications:[], dismissed:[], profile:{"agentid":"", visitorid:"109156be-c4fb-41ea-b1b4-efe1671c580f", displayName:"", email:"", company:"", activeSubscriptionid:"", accountStanding:"good", bio:"", emailVerified:true, location:"", website:"", avatarUrl:"", numFollowers:0, numFollowing:0, numOrganizations:0, allowedRoles:[], relationship:{}, created:"", updated:"", tags:[], abTests:{"buckets":{"landingPageVideo":{"name":"video", value:1}, openAccessTwo:{"name":"normal", value:0}, sidedoorVideo:{"name":"play-video", value:1}}}, orgMode:"", orgDetails:"", level:"", userCapabilities:{}}, requestsFetching:false, authorizedClients:[], isLoggedIn:false, onboardThisSession:false, token:"eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJwcm9kLXVzZXItY2xpZW50IiwiaXNzIjoiYXV0aG9yaXR5OmRhdGFkb3R3b3JsZDo6MEJGMEVCRDMtMkRFNy00OUZCLUI4N0ItQUQwMzA1N0JCODlFIiwiaWF0IjoxNTM4NDkxMzM0LCJyb2xlIjpbXSwiZXhwIjoxNTM4NTc3NzM0LCJ2aXNpdG9yaWQiOiIxMDkxNTZiZS1jNGZiLTQxZWEtYjFiNC1lZmUxNjcxYzU4MGYiLCJnZW5lcmFsLXB1cnBvc2UiOnRydWUsImF1dGhvcml0eWlkcyI6WyJkYXRhZG90d29ybGQiXX0.9zL3wK5ceD8ylOykw30wuN5JQLPNjArVYo7H-1R85OvTb2hHPTKekcZKYoW-fLhZhnRH22PXTfg23RD__wK3wA"}, discussion:{}, routing:{"locationBeforeTransitions":null}, siteStatus:{"uploadsOperational":true, queryOperational:true, websiteOperational:true, downloadsOperational:true, shouldAskReload:false, shouldForceReload:false, incidentName:"", incidentMessage:"", pageStatus:"none"}, loginModal:{"show":false}, signUpModal:{"show":false, treatment:null, treatmentProps:null}, linkedOnboardModal:{"show":false}, queries:{}, requestInfo:{"pathsMarkedAs404":[], metadata:{}}, integration:{"activeIntegrations":[]}, clients:{}, events:{"status":"closed", meta:{}}}{"analytics":{"snowplow_pixel":"d2vtrn3jrzj4cp.cloudfront.net", segment_id:"IXhtZmPohuGM60VHk59cdSbWqWQBB7aR"}, filestack_media_key:"AhpzUeRlHRGCiCUDy2Tz3z", filestack_dataset_key:"AuM8NdQnIQGE3NOBFdr6wz", filestack_dataset_strings_url:"https:\u002F\u002Fcdn.filepicker.io\u002Fapi\u002Ffile\u002F2OkHIxqQqq0DvgBPfiAh", filestack_max_upload_size:524288000, iframely_key:"e4239223dd4ad21531b3a044840d5898", sentry_dsn_client:"https:\u002F\u002F78d03c5189424a139f3e29423a60f67f@app.getsentry.com\u002F78710", version_build:"b003207", version_commit:"96f0da448", version_check_interval:60000, csrf_cookie_name:"_csrf", csrf_header_name:"x-csrf-token", analytics_log_to_console:false, ...]
Index: []

[0 rows x 155 columns]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do what it says on the data.world site.

Click the **Download** link (at the top right), Share URL and use either:

**To share a secure download link:**

```
https://query.data.world/s/xxxxxxxlink_codexxxxxxxx
```

**To import:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://query.data.world/s/xxxxxxxlink_codexxxxxxxx')
```

**Note: my links have been edited to not work, you may provide your own link.**